# Operator [] long and short versions

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

What is the advantage of using the longer version `(something).operator[]()` instead of simply `(something)[]`?

For example :

```
std::array<int, 10> arr1;
std::array<int, 10> arr2;

for(int i = 0; i < arr1.size(); i++) 
    std::cout << arr1[i] << ' '; 
    std::cout << std::endl;

for(int i = 0; i < arr2.size(); i++) 
    std::cout << arr2.operator[](i) << ' '; 
    std::cout << std::endl;
```

Comment: there is no advantage really. You can use the second one for pointers though: `arr2->operator[](i)`

Answer (score 1):

There is none. The `[]` is just syntactic sugar for `operator[]` on user-defined types. You only need the `operator` syntax when you define these functions yourself. This goes for all operators like `operator()`, `operator[]`, `operator new`, `operator=`, ...

Answer (score 0):

syntactic sugar

compiled with g++ -g -std=gnu++0x ...

```
0000000000400554 <main>:
#include <array>

int main() {
  400554:       55                      push   %rbp
  400555:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  400558:       48 83 ec 60             sub    $0x60,%rsp

    std::array<int, 10> arr1;
    std::array<int, 10> arr2;

    arr1[6];
  40055c:       48 8d 45 d0             lea    -0x30(%rbp),%rax
  400560:       be 06 00 00 00          mov    $0x6,%esi
  400565:       48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  400568:       e8 19 00 00 00          callq  400586 <std::array<int, 10ul>::operator[](unsigned long)>

    arr2.operator[](6);
  40056d:       48 8d 45 a0             lea    -0x60(%rbp),%rax
  400571:       be 06 00 00 00          mov    $0x6,%esi
  400576:       48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  400579:       e8 08 00 00 00          callq  400586 <std::array<int, 10ul>::operator[](unsigned long)>
  40057e:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
}
  400583:       c9                      leaveq
  400584:       c3                      retq
  400585:       90                      nop
```

Comment: yeah, I picked 33 originally just to make it easier to spot in the assembly. switched to 6